# Xamarin Forms File Picker not showing camera roll or image gallery on ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I"m using the xamarin.plugin.filepicker nuget in a Xamarin Forms project.  The picker does not show the user's camera roll or local image gallery on iOS
It only shows 'Icloud Drive' and 'Recently Deleted' folder locations instead.  I need to show the camera roll location if possible

```
  private async void PickImage_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        string[] fileTypes = null;

        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
        {
            fileTypes = new string[] { "image/png", "image/jpeg" };
        }

        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
        {
            fileTypes = new string[] { "public.image" }; // same as iOS constant UTType.Image
        }

        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.UWP)
        {
            fileTypes = new string[] { ".jpg", ".png" };
        }

        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.WPF)
        {
            fileTypes = new string[] { "JPEG files (*.jpg)|*.jpg", "PNG files (*.png)|*.png" };
        }

        await PickAndShowFile(fileTypes);
    }

    private async Task PickAndShowFile(string[] fileTypes)
    {
        try
        {
            var pickedFile = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile(fileTypes);

            if (pickedFile != null)
            {
                FileNameLabel.Text = pickedFile.FileName;
                FilePathLabel.Text = pickedFile.FilePath;

                if (pickedFile.FileName.EndsWith("jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                    || pickedFile.FileName.EndsWith("png", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    FileImagePreview.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => pickedFile.GetStream());
                    chosenImageBytes = GetImageStreamAsBytes(pickedFile.GetStream());
                    FileImagePreview.IsVisible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    FileImagePreview.IsVisible = false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            FileNameLabel.Text = ex.ToString();
            FilePathLabel.Text = string.Empty;
            FileImagePreview.IsVisible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1539

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Xamarin Media Plugin for that purpose.

Comment: Did you visit their github page? It has required examples and explanations.

Comment: As stated here, you just cannot do it with filepicker on ios: https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1539

Comment: @NickKovalsky thanks for the tip, but I am not sure where did I say that you should use the filepicker.